# c# triangle with number nested

Tags: c#, nested

need some homework help

Develop a C# console application that displays the two (2) following patterns separately, one below the other. Use for loops (hint:  nested) to generate the patterns. All asterisks should be displayed by a single statement of the form Console.Write("*"); which displays the asterisks leading up to the number value shown in the example. A statement of the form Console.WriteLine(); can be used to move to the next line. Note the sequence of each number in turn.  Remember that this is two separate sets of loops which are used to generate these two patterns.  You will need to deduce how the numbers are computed (they are the result of a computation) and where that computation will be placed in the loop structures.  You may not hardcode the displayed numbers into your loops.

trying to get the following pattern but my code gets me the right number and spacing but not the wright amount of stars with the number at the end. do i need to combine my write statements? should i have a formula that uses the counter integer) any help is appreciated.

```
*2
**4
***6
****8
*****10
******12
*******14
********16
*********18
**********20

**********20 
*********18
********16
*******14
******12
*****10
****8
***6
**4
*2
```

```
using System;
{
    public class Program
    {
        const string STAR = "*";
        const string SPACE = " ";
        const int COUNTER = 10;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            firsthalf();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static public void firsthalf()
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < COUNTER; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c <= r; c++)
                {
                    Console.Write(STAR);
                    Console.Write("{0}", (r + 1) * 2);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the print statement for the number `Console.Write("{0}", (r + 1) * 2);` outside the second loop

```
for (int r = 0; r < COUNTER; r++)
{
     for (int c = 0; c <= r; c++)
          Console.Write(STAR);    

     Console.WriteLine("{0}", (r + 1) * 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        f(1, 5, ascending: true);
        f(1, 10, ascending: false);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void f(int start, int count, bool ascending)
    {
        var indices = Enumerable.Range(start, count);
        if (!ascending) indices = indices.Reverse();
        foreach (int index in indices)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= index; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(2 * index);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace SOFAcrobatics
{
    public static class Launcher
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            Int32 n = 0;
            Boolean locker = false;
            for (Int32 i = 2 ; i <= 38 ; i+= 2)
            {
                n = ((i > 20) ? (40 - i) : i);
                if (n == 20 && !locker)
                {
                    locker = true;
                    i -= 2;
                }
                for (Int32 j = 1; j <= (n / 2); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write('*');
                }
                Console.WriteLine(n);
            }
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Took a combination of a few answers and i really appreciate the help.

```
using System;


public class Program
{
const string STAR = "*";
const string SPACE = " ";
const int COUNTER = 10;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  firsthalf();
  sechalf();

  Console.ReadLine();
 }

 static public void firsthalf()
 {
  for (int r = 0; r < COUNTER; r++)
  {
     for (int c = 0; c <= r; c++)
        Console.Write(STAR);

     Console.WriteLine("{0}", (r + 1) * 2);
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}


static public void sechalf()
{
  for (int r = COUNTER; r > 0; r--)
  {
     for (int c = 0; c < r; c++)
        Console.Write(STAR);

     Console.WriteLine("{0}", (r + 0) * 2);
     //Console.WriteLine();
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}
}
```